# Typing sequences recursively in Overleaf

Tags: amsmath, cases

I'm trying to type the following sequence recursively on Overleaf but I'm not exactly sure how to format it exactly as it is shown below. More specifically, I need help on how to type the info past the left brace.

[image]

Comment: this seems to be a general tex question unrelated to overleaf specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a new type of `cases` using `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcases{centercases}{\quad}
  {\hfil$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}
  {$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{\lbrace}{.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
a_{n}=
\begin{centercases}
  1         & n=1 \\
  a_{n-1}+4 & n>1
\end{centercases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the output obtained with `cases` is more frequently used:

[image]